# how to print after the keyword from python?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

i have following string in python

```
b'{"personId":"65a83de6-b512-4410-81d2-ada57f18112a","persistedFaceIds":["792b31df-403f-4378-911b-8c06c06be8fa"],"name":"waqas"}'
```

I want to print the all alphabet next to keyword "name" such that my output should be

```
waqas
```

Note the waqas can be changed to any number so i want print any name next to keyword name using string operation or regex?

Comment: It's much easier to read JSON using the `json` module instead of dealing with disassembling the strings yourself.

Comment: How did you get the string into Python? It may be possible to make it easier on you by reading the data directly into a dict, instead of a byte-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decode the string since it is binary `b`. Then use `literal eval` to make the dictionary, then you can access by `key`

```py
>>> s = b'{"personId":"65a83de6-b512-4410-81d2-ada57f18112a","persistedFaceIds":["792b31df-403f-4378-911b-8c06c06be8fa"],"name":"waqas"}'
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s.decode())['name']
'waqas'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you should be reading your data into your program in a different manner than you are doing now.

If I assume your data is inside a JSON file, try something like the following, using the built-in `json` module:

```
import json

with open(filename) as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)    
print(data['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string into a dictionary with `json.loads()`

```py
import json
mystring = b'{"personId":"65a83de6-b512-4410-81d2-ada57f18112a","persistedFaceIds":["792b31df-403f-4378-911b-8c06c06be8fa"],"name":"waqas"}'
mydict = json.loads(mystring)
print(mydict["name"])
# output 'waqas'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a more algorithmic way to extract the value of `name`:

```
s = b'{"personId":"65a83de6-b512-4410-81d2-ada57f18112a",\
"persistedFaceIds":["792b31df-403f-4378-911b-8c06c06be8fa"],\
"name":"waqas"}'

s = s.decode("utf-8")

key = '"name":"'
start = s.find(key) + len(key)
stop = s.find('"', start + 1)

extracted_string = s[start : stop]
print(extracted_string)
```

output

```
waqas
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the string into a proper `JSON` Format by removing b from the string using substring in python suppose you have a variable `x` :

```
import json
x = x[1:];
dict = json.loads(x) //convert JSON string into dictionary
print(dict["name"])
```